# TimeoutException on ViewPager setAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, crashlytics, fragmentpageradapter, crashlytics-android

I am developing Android App and I am using view pager inside a fragment but when I tried to setAdapter it's showing me Failed to execute a task.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Here how I am setting Adapter inside fragment:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    tabLayout.getTabCount(), drugAdherenceDto, selectedDate);

            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
    E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
        java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:177)
            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:320)
            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:300)
            at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
```

When I debug further put try-catch and I found that It's throwing:

```
stack overflow exception
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?